# Java Stream - throw exception in filter and return a list

Tags: java, list, exception, lambda, java-stream

I have created a Java stream:

```
List<Student> getStudentWithSameGrade(List<Student> students, Grade grade) {
    return students.stream().filter(s -> s.getGradeId().equals(grade.getGid())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above code returns a `List<Student>` that satisfies the `filter` check but I want to throw an exception for a student/list of students that don't satisfy this check. I tried doing something like this,

```
return students.stream().filter(s -> s.getGradeId().equals(grade.getGid())).findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(ENTITY_NOT_FOUND));
```

However, the above code snippet returns a single student object instead of a list. I am relatively new to the `Stream` concept so would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: It is not so clear what you want to do, could you maybe show what behavior you want using for-loops?

Comment: The only way to throw an exception from a Stream is using the Optional#orElseThrow method.

Comment: @Jason he is already using this method

Comment: @Jason but how do I use `Collectors.toList()` and `orElseThrow()` in the same statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be simply to check:

```
List<Student> getStudentWithSameGrade(List<Student> students, Grade grade) {
    List<Student> students = students.stream().filter(s -> s.getGradeId().equals(grade.getGid())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (students.isEmpty()) throw new EntityNotFoundException(ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
    else return students;
}
```

If you **really** need to stick to stream api, you could define your own collector:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, T> toNonEmptyList() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        list -> {
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            return list;
        }
    );
}
```

And then:

```
return students.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.getGradeId().equals(grade.getGid()))
    .collect(toNonEmptyList());
```